# Android Location Coordinates Low Accuracy Using 3G triangulation

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation, location

I am using 3G as my location provider for an android application.
For my **onLocationChanged** function , I am using the if statement

```
if(location.getAccuracy()<100){
//do some stuff here.
}
```

This condition is not being satisfied while being on 3G. So my guess is that 3G is not providing enough accuracy.

**My question is: How accurate, on average, is 3G location triangulation? what do you suggest I set the value?**

Answer (score 1):

That depends on multiple factors, like signal strength, triangulation of 3G/4G towers... but the truth is 3G is not accurate like GPS is. but is more battery efficient.

Take a look on this topic: [Android:GPS coordinates are different in 3G and wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5855262/3640637)

Comment: Thanks. I have already read this thread. Wi-fi is working great and is getting the accuracy within 100 meters. The problem is with 3G with that specific provider. Do you know whether, in general, wi-fi is more accurate than 3g?

Comment: with wi-fi google can accurate the provider by the location of the hotspot (router) thats why the accuracy is 30-200 meters (w-fi range).

Comment: and do you have any idea about 3g? what would be a good (average) accuracy value for it?